# how to get MAC address for wireless access point?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, mac-address, wireless-access-point

How can I get the MAC address for the wireless access point in Ubuntu?

Comment: Not programming...

Comment: @leppie: it *could* be a programming question, if the asker would say, instead, "in bash, how do I..."

Comment: @MAMProgr:  Do you want to know how to do this in bash, or using the GUI?  If you want to use the GUI to do this, this question should be asked on [su](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: @David: The fact that it is tagged with ubuntu and not some programming platform or language pretty much excludes that hypothesis.

Comment: @leppie: doesn't the bash shell come with ubuntu?  Until the asker gives more information, I don't think there's much of a onclusion that could be drawn.

Comment: @David: Shell scripting in such a trivial form is NOT programming.

Comment: @studio anytime! :)

Answer (score 7):

Either connect to the point, and do

```
iwconfig | grep "Access Point"
```

or find your access point in the output of

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

*(if you have wireless interface called not `wlan0`, substitute appropriately)*.

Comment: Wonderful. Both commands show the access point MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `arping` utility with your AP's IP as an argument:

```
$ arping 192.168.0.1
ARPING 192.168.0.1 from 192.168.0.200 eth0
Unicast reply from 192.168.0.1 [00:48:6C:38:B7:4D]  0.660ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.0.1 [00:48:6C:38:B7:4D]  0.590ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.0.1 [00:48:6C:38:B7:4D]  0.610ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.0.1 [00:48:6C:38:B7:4D]  0.410ms
Sent 4 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 4 response(s)
```

You can see the MAC address in the reply.

Answer (score 1):

linux command

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

is a very good one, however if you'll have lot's of WIFI AP around (like in the multi-floor buildings) - you'll get the following error message in result:

```
wlan0    Failed to read scan data : Argument list too long
```

in this case the only way to get MAC of your AP would be:

```
sudo iw wlan0 scan | egrep "^BSS|SSID:" |grep -n1 <your AP name>
```

as an output you'll get following:

```
104-BSS 44:ce:7d:7b:e7:9e(on wlan0)
105:    SSID: <your AP name>
```

where 1st line would be the MAC and 2nd line would be your AP name

on MacOSX similar information could be possible to obtain by executing:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -s |grep <your AP name>
```

as an output you'll get following:

```
<your AP name> 44:ce:7d:7b:e7:9e -58  1       Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try dmesg when connecting/connected to wireless access point:

```
$ dmesg | grep "probe to"
```

On my box (Fedora 14), I get line like this:

```
[ 5257.283188] wlan0: direct probe to 00:23:eb:3a:99:e0 (try 1)
```

Not sure whether under different kernel or other configuration on other distro like ubuntu has the same info printed out. Please try.